# Keycloak with OpenIdConnect external identityprovider

Tags: identityserver3, openid-connect, keycloak

I have a external `openidconnect` identity provider registered with `Keycloak`. When the client app tries to access the protected resource it gets redirected to `KeyCloak` login page. On the login page I have the external `openidconnect` provider buttons enabled. Once the user clicks on the button he is taken to the external identity provider (which is identityserver3 instance). The external provider does authenticate the user and send back a code.

Now the redirecturl for the registered client in the external identity provider is that of keycloak's. So after authentication is successful at the external IDP it send back the code(because it is Auth code flow) to keycloak at a redirect url:

http://localhost:5555/auth/realms/QA/broker/keycloak-client/endpoint?code=7bcf5157105199d50874e64eabf03858&state=wQhNIEKW0Ws6CotZg2EsvOorjDVQlWVvobcM2skPSXo.keycloak-client&session_state=rhgu-BXT8FniG9Z-UARKpp_f-V1nLN-VxFmSE3PSxDg.99b2d903367208e4261fefa475afb1eb

In the URL if you see it ends with `endpoint`. I don't think that's correct but I cannot change it in KeyCloak (it's disabled) and because of that in the external IDP client configuration.

KeyCloak does not understand above url and errors out with a message "unexpected error when authenticating with Identity Provider"

Isn't `KeyCloak` supposed to understand the code flow and make another request for token after receiving the code. Then the external IDP will respond with token and `Keycloak` will send back that token to client(will also store it for future use).

Can someone please share some knowledge on how `Keycloak` works with external openidconnect ID provider with code flow.

Comment: Hi. Did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Usually the redirect URI for external identity providers take the form of `{keycloak-host}/auth/realms/{realm}/broker/{provider}/endpoint`. You have to specify this as the redirect URI when you register your client in the external identity provider. Once the user is authenticated through the external IdP, authorization code will be sent to this url, which in turn will redirect it to the redirect url of your client application (specified when registering the client in Keycloak).

`Unexpected error when authenticating with Identity Provider` is the general error message sent by Keycloak for several errors that occur during the OAuth flow. You won't be able to determine the actual cause without going through the stack trace or the logs in the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because keyclaok is unable to get token from identityserver3 by exchanging authorization code. Where did you hosted identityserver3? Does it have a real ca certificate or you are using self sign certificate? Have you configured `client_id` , `secret`, `token endpoint` properly in keycloak external IDP configuration? You can test manually my posting `client_id`, `secret`, `code` (that you received) in token endpoint of identityserver3.